# How to use translation in global validation with redux-form validation

Tags: translation, admin-on-rest

When trying to use validation in a global validator with this code:

```
errors.fieldMissing = [translate('aor.validation.fieldMissing')];
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `errorText` supplied to `TextField`, expected a ReactNode.
```

Without the translation(), just setting the error to an array of a string, everything works as expected.

How can translation() be used in global validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example(edited from [AOR example posts](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/example/posts.js)):

```
<SimpleForm defaultValue={{ average_note: 0 }} validate={(values, props) => {
    const errors = {};
    ['title', 'teaser'].forEach((field) => {
        if (!values[field]) {
            errors[field] = [props.translate('aor.validation.required')];
        }
    });
...
```

A short example of translate hoc and translate props:

```
import { translate as translator } from 'admin-on-rest';
const Title = translator(({ record, translate }) => <span>{record ? translate('title.product', { name: record.name }) : ''}</span>);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that did the trick! for clarification, why do `props.translate()` and `translate()` have different behaviours in this scenario?

Comment: The translate you import from admin-on-rest is a higher order component. It gives its wrapped component a translate prop. This translate prop does the actual string translation. You can do this to avoid confusion: `import { translate as translator } from 'admin-on-rest'`.